# Ubuntu - node permission issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, permissions, yo

Trying to run `yo angular:app myWebApp` shows me following Error:

[image]

What should I do to overcome the permission error?

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo with your command. Like
sudo yo angular:app myWebApp
. If it asks for your password enter it and it will work.

Comment: It looks like you don't have access to this file may be due to the file or folder permissions.

Comment: Any suggestion , how to overcome the same?